# SQL query need nulls to appear

Tags: sql, t-sql, null

Im using SQL Server manager 2008.

I have a query as follows:

```
SELECT dbo.iLines.Part,
   dbo.iLines.Pg,
   SUM(dbo.iLines.Qty) as sales6months,
   dbo.iLines.Prefix       
FROM 
   Autopart.dbo.iLines
RIGHT JOIN
   dbo.product  
ON
   dbo.product.keycode = dbo.ilines.part                 

where  prefix = 'i'
   and ([datetime] > dateadd(month, -6, getdate()))
   and dbo.ilines.part = 'BK939'

group by 
   dbo.ilines.pg,
   dbo.ilines.part,
   dbo.ilines.prefix

order by sales6months desc
```

So to explain, I want to get the last 6month sales on all the products in the product table.

The problem is the fact that some products wont have any sales.  I still need them to show.
So what I'm asking is to show the last 6month sales on ALL products including 0 sales.

"iLines" is the table causing the problem since the part number only exists in there if there has been a sale.

I know there may be a way doing multiple query's etc.  But I need this all in 1 query ONLY.

I tried letting null through but does nothing plus its really scary using nulls hehe.

Any code snippet to add to this query would be super awesome!!

Many thanks!

Also if you need any more info just ask!

UPDATE! 
Yes sorry Datetime only exists in Ilines.

Ilines = table of sales
Product = just a table of all our products

Heres the main query, its meant to pull the top "n" sold parts in the last 6 months.
It works except like I said it doesn't show parts that have not sold.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyPareto]
@pgParam varchar(255)
AS
SELECT
   i.pg,
   dbo.OldParetoAnalysis.Pareto,
   i.part,
   i.sales6months,
   a.LostSales6Months,
   dbo.NewParetoAnalysis.Pareto

FROM
OPENQUERY(SACBAUTO, 'SELECT dbo.iLines.Part,
                            dbo.iLines.Pg,
                            SUM(dbo.iLines.Qty) as   sales6months,
                            dbo.iLines.Prefix 
                     FROM Autopart.dbo.iLines 
                     where prefix = ''i''
                     and [datetime] > dateadd(month, -6,    getdate())
                     group by 
                     dbo.ilines.pg,
                     dbo.ilines.part,
                     dbo.ilines.prefix
                     order by sales6months desc') i
RIGHT JOIN
dbo.OldParetoAnalysis
on
i.part collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = dbo.OldParetoAnalysis.Part
INNER JOIN
dbo.NewParetoAnalysis
ON
dbo.OldParetoAnalysis.Part collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS =     dbo.NewParetoAnalysis.Part
LEFT JOIN
OPENQUERY(SACBAUTO, 'SELECT dbo.aLines.Part,
                            dbo.aLines.Pg,
                            SUM(dbo.aLines.Qty) as LostSales6Months,
                            dbo.aLines.Prefix 
                     FROM Autopart.dbo.aLines 
                     where prefix = ''d''
                     and [datetime] > dateadd(month, -6, getdate())
                     group by 
                     dbo.alines.pg,
                     dbo.alines.part,
                     dbo.alines.prefix
                     order by LostSales6Months desc') a
ON
dbo.NewParetoAnalysis.Part collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = a.part
WHERE
    i.pg = @pgParam
GROUP BY
   i.pg,
   dbo.OldParetoAnalysis.Pareto,
   i.part,
   i.sales6months,
   a.LostSales6Months,
   dbo.NewParetoAnalysis.Pareto
ORDER BY
dbo.OldParetoAnalysis.Pareto asc
```

think of the pareto as a league of the best parts.
Hopefully this will help, I tried to avoid adding it as it may put some people off commenting.

Ok new update, this open query works!!!

```
SELECT                      
                        dbo.product.Keycode,
                        dbo.iLines.Pg,
                        SUM(COALESCE(dbo.iLines.Qty, 0)) as sales6months,
                        dbo.iLines.Prefix 
                     FROM 
                        Autopart.dbo.product
                     LEFT OUTER JOIN
                        Autopart.dbo.ilines
                     ON
                        dbo.product.keycode = dbo.ilines.part
                        AND ([datetime] > dateadd(month, -6, getdate()) OR [datetime] is null )
                     WHERE
                        (dbo.iLines.Prefix = 'i' OR dbo.iLines.Prefix is null)
                        AND dbo.product.keycode = 'BK939'
                     group by 
                        dbo.ilines.pg,
                        dbo.product.keycode,
                        dbo.ilines.prefix
                     order by sales6months desc#
```

BUT when i then join with my pareto table as follows:

```
SELECT
   i.pg,
   dbo.OldParetoAnalysis.Pareto,
   i.keycode,
   i.sales6months


FROM
OPENQUERY(SACBAUTO, 'SELECT                     
                        dbo.product.Keycode,
                        dbo.iLines.Pg,
                        SUM(COALESCE(dbo.iLines.Qty, 0)) as sales6months,
                        dbo.iLines.Prefix 
                     FROM 
                        Autopart.dbo.product
                     LEFT OUTER JOIN
                        Autopart.dbo.ilines
                     ON
                        dbo.product.keycode = dbo.ilines.part
                        AND ([datetime] > dateadd(month, -6, getdate()) OR [datetime] is null )/* must be this*/
                     WHERE
                        (dbo.iLines.Prefix = ''i'' OR dbo.iLines.Prefix is null)
                     group by 
                        dbo.ilines.pg,
                        dbo.product.keycode,
                        dbo.ilines.prefix
                     order by sales6months desc') i
LEFT JOIN
dbo.OldParetoAnalysis
on
i.keycode collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = dbo.OldParetoAnalysis.Part
WHERE i.pg = '40' AND i.keycode = 'BK939'
```

The results go back the same, So this means the problem is when i go to join, BUT old pareto does contain the part number, and ive also tried changing the joins....Im hoping this has narrowed down the search for the problem and im Hoping some one has an idea why this is happening!

FINAL UPDATE!
Wow this is looong, but finally i figured out the problem, I had to recheck using the product tables PG field!!!!! since it wont be null!! here's the code!

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyPareto32TEST]
@pgParam varchar(255)

AS
SELECT
   i.pg,
   dbo.OldParetoAnalysis.Pareto,
   i.keycode,
   i.sales6months,
   a.LostSales6Months,
   dbo.NewParetoAnalysis.Pareto

FROM
OPENQUERY(SACBAUTO, 'SELECT                      
                    dbo.product.Keycode,
                    dbo.iLines.Pg,
                    dbo.product.pg as ppg,
                    SUM(COALESCE(dbo.iLines.Qty, 0)) as sales6months,
                    dbo.iLines.Prefix 
                 FROM 
                    Autopart.dbo.product
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    Autopart.dbo.ilines
                 ON
                    dbo.product.keycode = dbo.ilines.part
                    AND ([datetime] > dateadd(month, -6, getdate()) OR [datetime] is null )
                 WHERE
                    (dbo.iLines.Prefix = ''i'' OR dbo.iLines.Prefix is null)
                 group by 
                    dbo.ilines.pg,
                    dbo.product.keycode,
                    dbo.ilines.prefix,
                    dbo.product.pg
                 order by sales6months desc') i
RIGHT JOIN
dbo.OldParetoAnalysis
on
i.keycode collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = dbo.OldParetoAnalysis.Part
AND (i.pg = @pgParam or (i.pg is null AND i.ppg  = @pgParam))
INNER JOIN
dbo.NewParetoAnalysis
ON
dbo.OldParetoAnalysis.Part collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS =   dbo.NewParetoAnalysis.Part

LEFT JOIN
OPENQUERY(SACBAUTO, 'SELECT                      
                    dbo.product.Keycode,
                    dbo.aLines.Pg,
                    SUM(COALESCE(dbo.aLines.Qty, 0)) as lostsales6months,
                    dbo.aLines.Prefix 
                 FROM 
                    Autopart.dbo.product
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    Autopart.dbo.alines
                 ON
                    dbo.product.keycode = dbo.alines.part
                    AND ([datetime] > dateadd(month, -6, getdate()) OR [datetime] is null )
                 WHERE
                    (dbo.aLines.Prefix = ''d'' OR dbo.aLines.Prefix is null)
                 group by 
                    dbo.alines.pg,
                    dbo.product.keycode,
                    dbo.alines.prefix
                 order by lostsales6months desc') a
ON
dbo.NewParetoAnalysis.Part collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = a.keycode
WHERE(i.pg = @pgParam or (i.pg is null AND i.ppg  = @pgParam) AND dbo.NewParetoAnalysis.Pareto is not null)
GROUP BY
   i.pg,
   dbo.OldParetoAnalysis.Pareto,
   i.keycode,
   i.sales6months,
   a.LostSales6Months,
   dbo.NewParetoAnalysis.Pareto
ORDER BY
dbo.OldParetoAnalysis.Pareto asc
```

Comment: UPDATED: still no luck, tried most posts on here, tried combining some, what's very strange is the data I receive is Always the same.

Comment: Updated response: note it helps if group by/ select contain an element from the part table, otherwise the right join isn't going to do much..

Comment: UPDATED my code, almost there!!!

Comment: You need to use `OUTER JOIN` join for the  pareto table as well.

Comment: ill repost as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres the code, just needed to check for PG from the product table and the ilines!!

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyPareto32TEST]
@pgParam varchar(255)

AS
SELECT
   i.pg,
   dbo.OldParetoAnalysis.Pareto,
   i.keycode,
   i.sales6months,
   a.LostSales6Months,
   dbo.NewParetoAnalysis.Pareto

FROM
OPENQUERY(SACBAUTO, 'SELECT                      
                    dbo.product.Keycode,
                    dbo.iLines.Pg,
                    dbo.product.pg as ppg,
                    SUM(COALESCE(dbo.iLines.Qty, 0)) as sales6months,
                    dbo.iLines.Prefix 
                 FROM 
                    Autopart.dbo.product
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    Autopart.dbo.ilines
                 ON
                    dbo.product.keycode = dbo.ilines.part
                    AND ([datetime] > dateadd(month, -6, getdate()) OR [datetime] is null )
                 WHERE
                    (dbo.iLines.Prefix = ''i'' OR dbo.iLines.Prefix is null)
                 group by 
                    dbo.ilines.pg,
                    dbo.product.keycode,
                    dbo.ilines.prefix,
                    dbo.product.pg
                 order by sales6months desc') i
RIGHT JOIN
dbo.OldParetoAnalysis
on
i.keycode collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = dbo.OldParetoAnalysis.Part
AND (i.pg = @pgParam or (i.pg is null AND i.ppg  = @pgParam))
INNER JOIN
dbo.NewParetoAnalysis
ON
dbo.OldParetoAnalysis.Part collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = dbo.NewParetoAnalysis.Part

LEFT JOIN
OPENQUERY(SACBAUTO, 'SELECT                      
                    dbo.product.Keycode,
                    dbo.aLines.Pg,
                    SUM(COALESCE(dbo.aLines.Qty, 0)) as lostsales6months,
                    dbo.aLines.Prefix 
                 FROM 
                    Autopart.dbo.product
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    Autopart.dbo.alines
                 ON
                    dbo.product.keycode = dbo.alines.part
                    AND ([datetime] > dateadd(month, -6, getdate()) OR [datetime] is null )
                 WHERE
                    (dbo.aLines.Prefix = ''d'' OR dbo.aLines.Prefix is null)
                 group by 
                    dbo.alines.pg,
                    dbo.product.keycode,
                    dbo.alines.prefix
                 order by lostsales6months desc') a
ON
dbo.NewParetoAnalysis.Part collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = a.keycode
WHERE(i.pg = @pgParam or (i.pg is null AND i.ppg  = @pgParam) AND dbo.NewParetoAnalysis.Pareto is not null)
GROUP BY
   i.pg,
   dbo.OldParetoAnalysis.Pareto,
   i.keycode,
   i.sales6months,
   a.LostSales6Months,
   dbo.NewParetoAnalysis.Pareto
ORDER BY
dbo.OldParetoAnalysis.Pareto asc
```

Answer (score 5):

The following condition filters out any row for which the `right join` fails:

```
dbo.ilines.part = 'BK939'
```

To fix it, move the condition to the join:

```
RIGHT JOIN
   dbo.product  
ON
   dbo.product.keycode = dbo.ilines.part                 
   and dbo.ilines.prefix = 'i'
   and dbo.ilines.part = 'BK939'
where  
   ([datetime] > dateadd(month, -6, getdate()))
```

Assuming `[datetime]` is a column of `product`, you can leave that in the `where` clause.

Comment: thanks for your reply, tried doing this adding datetime to the ON Join, since datetime is part of ilines, but it returns a row of nulls

Answer (score 3):

I would start from the table you want and the work myself do to the `joins`. You said you want `product`. Why not start with that table and then take a `LEFT JOIN` to the `iLines`?

Maybe something like this then:

```
SELECT 
    dbo.product.keycode AS part,
    dbo.iLines.Pg,
    SUM(dbo.iLines.Qty) as sales6months,
    dbo.iLines.Prefix       
FROM 
   dbo.product 
LEFT JOIN dbo.ilines  
    ON dbo.product.keycode = dbo.ilines.part
    AND dbo.ilines.prefix = 'i'
    and dbo.ilines.part = 'BK939'                 

where
    ([datetime] > dateadd(month, -6, getdate()))

group by 
   dbo.ilines.pg,
   dbo.product.keycode,
   dbo.ilines.prefix

order by sales6months desc
```

I don't know if the `[datetime]` column is coming from the `product` table or if is from the `ilines` table. If it is from the `product` table then the upper one will probably apply. If not then put that in the `LEFT JOIN` as well. Like this:

```
LEFT JOIN dbo.ilines  
        ON dbo.product.keycode = dbo.ilines.part
        AND dbo.ilines.prefix = 'i'
        and dbo.ilines.part = 'BK939' 
        AND ([datetime] > dateadd(month, -6, getdate()))
```

**EDIT**

It sound per your description that you want a `FULL OUTER JOIN`. So this join will be:

```
LEFT JOIN
dbo.OldParetoAnalysis
on
i.keycode collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = dbo.OldParetoAnalysis.Part
```

Like this:

```
FULL OUTER JOIN
dbo.OldParetoAnalysis
on
i.keycode collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = dbo.OldParetoAnalysis.Part
```

On msdn it says:

> To retain the nonmatching information by including nonmatching rows in
>   the results of a join, use a full outer join. SQL Server provides the
>   full outer join operator, FULL OUTER JOIN, which includes all rows
>   from both tables, regardless of whether or not the other table has a
>   matching value.

Reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518.aspx)

**EDIT2**

Have you tried with a RIGHT JOIN to the dbo.OldParetoAnalysis? Like this:

```
RIGHT JOIN
dbo.OldParetoAnalysis
on
i.keycode collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = dbo.OldParetoAnalysis.Part
```

**EDIT3**

On other thing you can try is that you create a temp table. It is not the neatest solution. But maybe something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp 
(
    Keycode VARCHAR(100),
    Pg VARCHAR(100),
    sales6months INT,
    Prefix VARCHAR(100)
)
```

And then insert then rows from the `OPENQUERY`

```
INSERT INTO #tmp(Keycode,Pg,sales6months,Prefix)
SELECT
    i.Keycode,
    i.pg,
    i.sales6months
    i.Prefix,
FROM
    OPENQUERY(SACBAUTO, 'SELECT                     
                        dbo.product.Keycode,
                        dbo.iLines.Pg,
                        SUM(COALESCE(dbo.iLines.Qty, 0)) as sales6months,
                        dbo.iLines.Prefix 
                     FROM 
                        Autopart.dbo.product
                     LEFT OUTER JOIN
                        Autopart.dbo.ilines
                     ON
                        dbo.product.keycode = dbo.ilines.part
                        AND ([datetime] > dateadd(month, -6, getdate()) OR [datetime] is null )/* must be this*/
                     WHERE
                        (dbo.iLines.Prefix = ''i'' OR dbo.iLines.Prefix is null)
                     group by 
                        dbo.ilines.pg,
                        dbo.product.keycode,
                        dbo.ilines.prefix
                     order by sales6months desc') i
```

And then us the temp table in the joins. Like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    #tmp AS i
    LEFT JOIN dbo.OldParetoAnalysis
    on
    i.keycode collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = dbo.OldParetoAnalysis.Part
    WHERE i.pg = '40' AND i.keycode = 'BK939'
```

Remember to drop the temp table after you are done. Like this:

```
DROP TABLE #tmp
```

**EDIT4**

If you have the original store procedure then the code should and it you are going with the temp table soulution then this might be of help:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyPareto]
@pgParam varchar(255)
AS

CREATE TABLE #tmp
(
    Keycode VARCHAR(100),--The type I don't know
    Pg VARCHAR(100),--The type I don't know
    sales6months INT,--The type I don't know
    Prefix VARCHAR(100)--The type I don't know
)
INSERT INTO #tmp(Keycode,Pg,sales6months,Prefix)
SELECT
    i.Keycode,
    i.pg,
    i.sales6months,
    i.Prefix
FROM
    OPENQUERY(SACBAUTO, 'SELECT                     
                        dbo.product.Keycode,
                        dbo.iLines.Pg,
                        SUM(COALESCE(dbo.iLines.Qty, 0)) as sales6months,
                        dbo.iLines.Prefix 
                     FROM 
                        Autopart.dbo.product
                     LEFT OUTER JOIN
                        Autopart.dbo.ilines
                     ON
                        dbo.product.keycode = dbo.ilines.part
                        AND ([datetime] > dateadd(month, -6, getdate()) OR [datetime] is null )/* must be this*/
                     WHERE
                        (dbo.iLines.Prefix = ''i'' OR dbo.iLines.Prefix is null)
                     group by 
                        dbo.ilines.pg,
                        dbo.product.keycode,
                        dbo.ilines.prefix
                     order by sales6months desc') i

SELECT
   i.pg,
   dbo.OldParetoAnalysis.Pareto,
   i.part,
   i.sales6months,
   a.LostSales6Months,
   dbo.NewParetoAnalysis.Pareto

FROM
#tmp i
RIGHT JOIN dbo.OldParetoAnalysis 
    on i.part collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = dbo.OldParetoAnalysis.Part
INNER JOIN dbo.NewParetoAnalysis 
    ON dbo.OldParetoAnalysis.Part collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS =     dbo.NewParetoAnalysis.Part
LEFT JOIN #tmp a 
    ON dbo.NewParetoAnalysis.Part collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = a.part
WHERE
    i.pg = @pgParam
GROUP BY
   i.pg,
   dbo.OldParetoAnalysis.Pareto,
   i.part,
   i.sales6months,
   a.LostSales6Months,
   dbo.NewParetoAnalysis.Pareto
ORDER BY
    dbo.OldParetoAnalysis.Pareto asc

DROP TABLE #tmp
```

Comment: this generated multipule results, tried adding it to my main query but the issue remains :(

Comment: thanks for that, although it doesnt work :( 0 results appear since ive added the part = bk939 to just see if it will appear

Comment: weird isnt it? the open query works pulling the data but when joined to the pareto table it does exactly the same again.....very very weird

Comment: ok i think it may be the where clause, in the open query the part appears, the sum apears as 0 but pg is NULL, so when i filter on the join to ask for pg = 40 it doesnt get passed.  only problem is if i check and allow null it throws in tons of other NUlls...how to get around this hmmm

Comment: crazy but worth a try, could you put this into the main query? dont really want to mess things up, never used temp tables before. by that i mean the stored procedure i posted

Answer (score 3):

Root of problem: Suspect where clause criteria is limiting out data that would otherwise be there due to right join.

Possible solutions

1. use or & Null on where clause critieria
2. move the whereclause to the join criteria already done in another example)
3. Use a union

This is using null on where clause. (REVISED) we all seemed to have missed the select needs to pull from PARTS! not ilines.

```
SELECT dbo.product.keycode as PART,
   dbo.iLines.Pg,
   SUM(coalesce(dbo.iLines.Qty,0)) as sales6months,
   dbo.iLines.Prefix       
FROM 
   Autopart.dbo.iLines
RIGHT JOIN
   dbo.product  
ON
   dbo.product.keycode = dbo.ilines.part                 

where  (prefix = 'i' or prefix is null)
   and (([datetime] > dateadd(month, -6, getdate())) OR [datetime] is null)
   and (dbo.ilines.part = 'BK939' or dbo.ilines.part is null)

group by 
   dbo.ilines.pg,
   dbo.product.keycode,
   dbo.ilines.prefix

order by sales6months desc
```

Comment: wont this still exclude parts that have not been sold? since datetime is causing the issue from the ilines table

Comment: if datetime is sourced from iliness then yes; but correctable by doing the is null on it as well.

Comment: im going insane, ive tried most the answers here and there isnt even change, not even saying its wrong, just nothing happens the data is exactly the same

Comment: I wouldn't expect this at all; so now I need to see some sample data.  Can you post some lines from ilines and product where values are not showing up and what you would expect to see given inputs?  The only other thing I can think of is that when the SUM(dboiLines.qty) is occuring a sum on NULL is null so the whole line is NULL... maybe we need to coalesce it to 0...  OMG>.. NM your SELECT needs to pull from product... there's the problem..

Comment: @Steven Smith  well there were multiple thigns wrong I think 1) the select needs to pull from product table if you want to see products.  2) sum on null may present problems, so I used coalese to substitute 0 instead of null when encountered. I changed group by to group on product keycode instead of ilines.prart.  Now the results should be there...

Comment: ill try this out tomorow, currently aint got access to my pc , since im ill at home, but yes the summing of null does seem to be the suspect here, good catch!

Comment: OK i really think it must be the datetime

Answer (score 2):

You need an outer join - something like this:

```
SELECT dbo.product.keycode, 
  dbo.iLines.Pg, 
  SUM(dbo.iLines.Qty) as sales6months, 
  dbo.iLines.Prefix        
FROM  
  dbo.product
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Autopart.dbo.iLines ON dbo.product.keycode = dbo.ilines.part
```

In youe query you are selecting only the sales with `prefix='i'`, and this will automatically exclude products that do not have a sale, so I am not sure how you want to handle that.

Answer (score 2):

You're still filtering on something that could be NULL from an outer join.  After you join to the Pareto table in the where clause:

```
WHERE i.pg = '40'
```

The source of that column (in your OPENQUERY statement) is dbo.ILines, which is outer joined to products, and will therefore be NULL if the product doesn't appear in the ILines set.  You may want to try:

```
WHERE ISNULL(i.pg, '40') = '40'
```

Of course, if i.pg can be NULL even where a record exists in the dbo.ILines table, then you may need to include the key from ILines in the original query and do something like:

```
WHERE ( i.pg = '40'
        OR i.<ILinesKeyField> IS NULL
      )
```

This makes sure that even if you have a NULL in dbo.ILines.Pg and the NULL field is NOT due to the outer join, the unwanted row still gets filtered.

Comment: how does this where clause work, how do i call the ilines keyfeild from an open query ??

Comment: To use the second version, you'd need to add a field that can't be NULL in the ILines table in the query wrapped in your opequery statement. I suggested the key, but any NOT NULL field will work.  I don't know whether the Pg field allows NULL.  If it does, then the first where clause above will accept rows with NULL in Pg where there is a row.  The second only allows rows with Pg 40 or no match at all in ILines.

Answer (score 1):

Why not select all from the product table and left join on Autopart.dbo.iLines?  This will give you all of the products and then join the iLines table where they match and do not match.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT
    dbo.iLines.Part,
    dbo.iLines.Pg,
    SUM(dbo.iLines.Qty) as sales6months,
    dbo.iLines.Prefix       
FROM Autopart.dbo.iLines
RIGHT JOIN dbo.product  
ON dbo.product.keycode = dbo.ilines.part
where  prefix = 'i'
and ([datetime] > dateadd(month, -6, getdate()))
and dbo.ilines.part = 'BK939'

group by 
    dbo.ilines.pg,
    dbo.ilines.part,
    dbo.ilines.prefix
union
SELECT
    dbo.iLines.Part,
    dbo.iLines.Pg,
    0 as sales6months,
    dbo.iLines.Prefix       
FROM Autopart.dbo.iLines
RIGHT JOIN dbo.product  
ON dbo.product.keycode = dbo.ilines.part
where  prefix = 'i'
and max([datetime]) < dateadd(month, -6, getdate())
and dbo.ilines.part = 'BK939'

group by 
    dbo.ilines.pg,
    dbo.ilines.part,
    dbo.ilines.prefix    
order by sales6months desc
```

Comment: doesnt work, errors saying it doesnt like the aggregate in WHERE clause